# How to override element.style without using !important

Tags: css, angular-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap popover in an angular form , where the popover's top and left is getting calculated automatically and I am not able to override it even after increasing the specificity ,
`div.popover.right.in.fade (element .style )` is always taking precedence over my css ,

```
.form-name .alert-container .name-alert .popover{
left: 95%;
top: 150px;
}
```

I need to know how I can override the element.style without using !important.

Comment: Set as an inline style.

Comment: You can't override inline styles no matter the specificity of your selector. Without using !important you may try tro hack around it (for example use different attributes like transform or margin to change the element position if this is what you need).

Comment: No way. Without using !important. It's not possible to override the css property. Instead u can rewrite the css style property with javascript like document.getElementBy(''URELEMENTID").style.left="95%";

Answer (score 0):

The boostrap stylesheet should be loaded first, your stylesheet second, this way your overwrites will be picked up.

This is called "cascading", from the documentation:

> **Cascading**
>
> This is the capability provided by some style sheet languages such as CSS to allow style information from several sources to be blended together. These could be, for instance, corporate style guidelines, styles common to a group of documents, and styles specific to a single document. By storing these separately, style sheets can be reused, simplifying authoring and making more effective use of network caching. The cascade defines an ordered sequence of style sheets where rules in later sheets have greater precedence than earlier ones. Not all style sheet languages support cascading.